# Threading issue when creating an object on thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am having issue with threading in C#.

This is the first time when I am using threads like this.

Code:

```
static string Basepathlogpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData).ToString() + "\\OwnCRMServices\\";
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(StartThread));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void StartThread(object Stateinfo)
    {
        var workthread = Thread.CurrentThread;
        var logger = new MgLogger(Basepathlogpath + "TrackingServer" + 
                                  "\\",LogFileName.CostumeAppName,"TrackingServer" + workthread.ManagedThreadId);
        Console.WriteLine($"New Logger instace created on ThreadID {workthread.ManagedThreadId}");
        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Hello from ThreadPool ID {workthread.ManagedThreadId}");
            if (logger == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Logger not exists");
            }
            else
            {
                logger.WriteToLog($"New Log from ThreadID {workthread.ManagedThreadId}",Severity.Informational);
                Thread.Sleep(10000);    
            }
            
        }
    }
```

The issue is that when I am creating `MgLogger` it's okay, but then when I try to write to the log file all of my threads are using the same instance of the `MgLogger`. I know this since I checked in the log file, the logger works fine since I am using it in multiple programs.

I would like to do that all of my threads have different `MgLogger`.

Do I am just making a silly mistake or what?

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible - as your borrowing a thread from the thread pool that it just happens to be the case that (at least sometimes) your being given the same thread to use each time/for each iteration, so maybe the managed thread id is always the same as you finish each thread *before* asking for another/the next thread from the pool.

Try using a static incremented 'int'/integer as a replacement of the the thread id and see if the result is the same - output it's value & the value of the managed thread id too.